# RecyclerView Click listener is not getting?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have an array of 600 items. I have inserted all the array items in a `RecyclerView` and they are scrolling well. But, when I try to access onClick listener it is not getting called. I also tried to Implement `View.OnClickListener` and Override `onClick` in my `ViewHolder` class, but its not working.

I want to Toast data of the clicked item in the list when user clicks one of the items in the view

**Adapter code is**

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>  {

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            implements View.OnClickListener {
        private String mItem;
        private TextView mTextView;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            view.setOnClickListener(this);
            mTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
        }

        public void setItem(String item) {
            mItem = item;
            mTextView.setText(item);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d("TAG", "onClick " + getPosition() + " " + mItem);
        }
    }

    private String[] mDataset;

    public MyAdapter(String[] dataset) {
        mDataset = dataset;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.setItem(mDataset[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.length;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not displaying any `Toast` in `onClick()`.

Comment: either use click listener on any child element or use touch event of recyclerview to get click event....check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick

Comment: You are only implementing an interface, but you are not attaching the listener to any view.